# In theory, could a woman that has fathers and mothers cromosome identical, be able to live?

Tags: dna

What Im getting at is something totally impossible, but im making some mental experiences.

1. Assuming I have a machine that can produce a living being just from a DNA code (like in the movie  The Fly). If I make a DNA sequnce, that has mothers and fathers cromosomes identical, would such a being be a monstrosity or a human being when it got out of the machine.
2. For such a person, when DNA recombination between 2 eqal cromosomes is done, it will just be creating clones if itself.
3. Now we introduce a new monstrosity, a male twin male version of the identical-cromosome woman, that only hase the Y Chromosome altered. His sperm cells too will all be the same.
4. when theese 2.people mate, it will produce a clone.

EDIT: 
To clarify my question number one.. Chromosome pair 1 has 2 chromosomes, one from father, one from mother. If theese two would be identical.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to invent some fantastic machine to create genetically identical animals. [This is done all the time in plant and animal breeding](http://www.informatics.jax.org/downloads/datasets/misc/genealogy/genealogy.pdf), just not with people. [It's accomplished by inbreeding over many generations.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inbred_strain). [Animals are typically about 98.6% identical after 20 generations of inbreeding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inbred_strain#Inbred_strains_in_the_lab).

The danger in inbreeding is the hidden presence of recessive traits in the parents that will be fatal (or at least deleterious) in the offspring, since the offspring will get two copies rather than one. Breeders find parent stock that can withstand such intensive inbreeding by trial and error. Of course mutations continue to occur after a genetically identical strain has been created, so [genetic drift is a problem for laboratories using identical strains of plants or animals](https://www.jax.org/news-and-insights/jax-blog/2018/march/only-you-can-prevent-genetic-drift).

Answer (score 2):

Geneticaly identical organisms are possible.  Lab animals are bred to be genetically identical.  Animals are inbred, with culling of animals that show recessive traits. Eventually there are no recessive traits except any which might arise by chance mutation.    This is also routinely done with livestock - a bull with desirable traits might be mated (via frozen sperm) his daughters, granddaughters, great granddaughters etc, each time with the offspring animal having a greater proportion of the bull's DNA.

If you mate 2 genetically identical organisms, you will not have a clone.  Gametes are scrambled via meiosis.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meiosis

[image: meiosis]

No new genetic material is introduced, but the chromosomes are resorted in random ways which result in slight variations gamete to gamete, and in the resulting progeny.

Comment: hmm, perhaps i wasnt clear enough with the question.  If X is a chromosome ( and XX is a chromosome pair), ill call it XX=XleftXright. My question is, couldn an organizm that has Xleft=Xright survive?

Comment: Typically when you have maternal twins the X chromosomes (and all the others chromosomes) are essentially identical. There is  nothing pathological per se about having an identical pair of chromosomes. It just depends on the presence or absence of recessive alleles.

Comment: To further elaborate, since my knowledge is limited in this topic:clarify:   Chromosome pair 1- has 2 chromosomes, one from father, one from mother. If theese two would be identical.